# PHP and AJAX: How to append json_encode data to multiple unique IDs <DIV>'s?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to append the data inside json_encode to my DIVs that are being created in my PHP WHILE loop. To be more clear [here is my fiddle for demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dgo88q74/).

I have one DIV with a unique ID: desks(the small box you see). 
When my "aht" button is clicked it runs show_aht.php.

I want my data "time" from show_aht.php to replace the number inside every appropriate "desk" DIV, so display the "time" value being retrieved from my script.

**Problem**: It is not displaying, I'm having problem how to append/replace using my unique ID

thanks in advance!

**map.php WHILE loops that executes queries to create Desk and Station DIV:**

```
//desks
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($desk_result)){ 
                //naming values from coordinates table
                $id       = $row['coordinate_id'];
                $x_pos    = $row['x_coord'];
                $y_pos    = $row['y_coord'];
                $sec_name = $row['section_name'];
                $sta_num  = $row['station_number'];
                $position = $row['ver_hor'];

                //draw a DIV box at its X,Y coordinate   
                //if the desks belong in the section names below then assign the class name to make desks horizontal
                $class = "desk_box_ver"; //by default make desks vertical, by assigning class name

                if($position == "horizontal"){
                    $class = "desk_box_hor";//assign the class name to make desks horizontal
                }
```

**THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE DATA "TIME" TO REPLACE the $sta_number value by using id = test_$id**

```
                    //output all desks being read from the query
                    echo '<div class="' . $class . ' id="test_'.$id.'" data-rel="' . $id . '" style="left:' . $x_pos . 'px;top:' . $y_pos.'px;">' . $sta_num . '</div>' . "\n";
            }//end while
```

map.php AJAX
**How can I append in the the FOR loop below my DIV with id = test_$id?**

```
<div id="aht"><!--aht button--> 
    <button id="aht_button">AHT</button>    
</div><!--aht button-->

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aht').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url : "show_aht.php",
                    data:{} , // do I need to pass data if i'm GET ting?
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data){
                         alert(data);
                         //NOT WORKING PLEASE HELP
                         for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                            $("#test_"+id).html(data[i])
                         }
                      }//end success
                });//end ajax
              });//end click
            });//end rdy
        </script>
```

**show_aht.php - json_encode part**

```
/**comparing usernames from both arrays*/
    $res = array();
    foreach($memo_data as $m){
        foreach($user_data as $u){
            //if theres a matching username 
            //display user and time
            if( ($m['memo_code'] == $u) && ($m['avg_handle_time'] != null) ){
                $res[] = substr($m['avg_handle_time'],0,-3);//removing decimals
            }
            //else if matching user but no time, do not display time
            elseif( ($m['memo_code'] == $u) && ($m['avg_handle_time'] == null) ){
                $res[] = "NA";
            }
        }
    }

    $final_res = json_encode($res);
    echo $final_res;
```

Comment: Can you add the results of a `console.log(data);` (in the success function) to your question?

Comment: @jeroen I added console.log(data); now what? thanks

Comment: Now look at your browser console to see the actual data. It's a debugging tool. It doesn't change whether or not your code works.

Comment: It should be a javascript object and the exact contents and structure determine how you should loop through it and then you need to decide where you add what.

Comment: I was asking the wrong question sorry, I updated everything please look above.

Comment: FWIW, If you do `console.log(dat=data);`, you can access the `dat` object directly in the console. Also, where is that LOG info coming from? Looks like your script is outputting something else?

Comment: @CurtisMattoon "LOG" is being outputed by itself on the console. "time: no info" if what I wrote on my code. I updated my description above and facing new problem. thanks

Comment: Aha. If there's an arrow to the left of the `Time: No Info...` block, click that and expand the object, then copy & paste back here. Otherwise, you might be dealing with a string, though I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: @CurtisMattoon theres no arrow. I updated the content above please look at it! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution here is the answer:

```
success : function(data){
console.log(data);
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // loop over results
    var divForResult = $('#desk_' + data[i]['station']); // look for div for this object
    if (divForResult.length) { // if a div was found
        divForResult.html(data[i]['aht_value']); // set inner HTML
    }
}
```

} // end success

Answer (score 1):

I'd do what @jeroen suggests. `console.log(data);` right after success. You could also try a `complete: function(data) { ...` and log the data that way there will always be a result.

Also, is there a particular reason you're using `POST`? It seems to me that you're `GET`ting data.

Comment: yes I think thats one of the problems, I need to use GET instead of POST. Ill update it now. I still dont see how using console.log will help me append the result to the different DIVs in my WHILE loop ?

Comment: Using `.append()` as you had it before will accomplish that. You're just using `console.log()` as a debugging tool.

Comment: I was asking the wrong question sorry, I updated everything please look above. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//NOT WORKING PLEASE HELP
   for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    $("#test_"+id).html(data[i])
   }
```

Of course it's not working, Inside your **.success** function, where are you trying to get the variable id ($("#test_"+**id**)) from? As far as I'm concerned you're using id, as a javascript variable. So.. is it initialized globally in the scope of javascript? If so, does the variable has any value?
Analyzing this, I concludes that right there, the JQuery is not appending due to id error.

If you use **$.POST**, make sure you pass on purpose some irrelevant data, just for tests. But sure, use **$.GET**.

Post some feedback to see what's going on after you fix it, or explain what is happening right there.

Comment: on the console it does say "id is is undefined". How can I initialize the "id" so I may use it for every "desk" DIV? I've been going on circles looking online

Comment: You did a for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++), right? Cause you want to add some data into divs/anything with id #test_1, #test_2 and so on, am I right? So you can easily use variable i from the loop, instead of id, put $("#test_"+i), and then you'll get #test_1, #test_2, and etc. Test it. But of course, the variable i is starting at 0, so make sure to handle it with your named ids to match.

Comment: It didn't do anything. I think I know where the problem is. I need to compare the username from show_aht.php with username from map.php. If they match thats how I will append the data inside the DIV.. im just a bit confused on how to do it first

Comment: In the other hand, we from stackflow are just a bit confused with exactly what you want to do hehe. If the problem was appending to the matching divs, follow my instructions, otherwise, I dont know what the real problem is hehe.